# Terms and agreement checkbox in simple form for

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to achieve something very simple but cannot get my head around it . I just wanted the user to select the terms and conditions and not be able to move forward without checking it . I decided to do it in client side validations .

View - Checkbox

```
<div class="fl">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
</div>
<div class="agree-txt">
    <span>I agree to <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>.</span>
</div>
```

View - Submit button

```
<%= f.button :submit, "Submit", :class=>"big-blue-btn" %>
    <a href = "#" class="text-link"> Sign Up as a User</a>
</li>
```

JS

```
$function validateCheckbox() {
    if ($('#checkbox').attr('checked')) {
        alert("you have to accept the terms first");
    }
});
```

Please do let me know how i can achieve the same , i know i am missing something very small but can't able to find it .

Comment: try this `if( $('#checkbox').is(':checked'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it the normal rails way . Posting it so it might help someone in future .

Added this to my user model

```
validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true
```

And in the view

```
<%=f.check_box :terms_of_service %>
```

You don't need to have this field in database , rails provides this by default . Do make sure you mention terms_of_service in attr_accessible in your model or else it will throw a mass alignment error .

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked'))
```

for the js-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.big-blue-btn', function () {
        if (validateCheckbox()){
            ... do your submit code ....
        }
    });
});

function validateCheckbox() {
    if (!$('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        alert("you have to accept the terms first");
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Personally for this type of onclick event I'd give your button an ID and use that instead.

Comment: I did this but i also needed to mention the same on submit action . Can you please shed some light there as it's a simple form_for and it isn't taking in onclick() .

Comment: instead of using a submit, why not use an on click event instead. I shall edit my answer to include this.

Comment: can you please guide me through . Newbie to js here .

Comment: I did use  the id after you mentioned

Comment: It's still going through without checking the checkbox .

Comment: modified your view so its just a button instead of a submit? 

<button type="button" class="big-blue-btn" id="...">Click Me!</button>

Comment: Actually it's a simple form for on a devise model , so won't really save the data on the form submitted if i do that .

Comment: Haven't got much experience with devise I'm afraid but you should be able to pass data back using AJAX and then redirect to your next page using window.location.href = "". You may need to ask another question about how to pass data back to devise.

Comment: Not used to devise I'm afraid, Pete's answer above looks quite elegant though if it works.

Comment: OR just had a nice idea disable all submits for your form on the page load e.g. after $(document).ready $('formname').submit(false); then enable it or disable it with each checkbox change. enable = $('formname').submit(true);

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a button whose type is submit, because if you do it, the form will get submitted even if the user is not satisfying the particular criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to prevent the form from submitting, which is done with the `preventDefault()` method on the event object. It's better to have the event trigger on the form submission rather than the button click. This is because it's possible to submit a form by hitting enter in a text field, not just clicking the submit button.

```
# view.html.erb
<%= form_for my_object, html: {id: 'signup-form'} do %>
  ...
<% end %>


/* signup.js */
jQuery(function(){
  $('#signup-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    if(!$('#checkbox').attr('checked')) {
      showTermsAndConditionsErrorMessage();
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('#checkbox :checkbox:checked').length > 0;
```

my above answer is wrong try this one.

```
if($("#checkbox-1").prop('checked') == true){
//do something
}
```

Comment: This will not work. This is setting the `checked` attribute to `false`. You need to use the getter and check the value.